# Javascript image refresh with preload, loading issues

Tags: javascript, html, preload

I have a small *.html file showing and regularly updating a *.png file.
To prevent flashing during the reload, I preload the image within the code.

Although I observe, that during some refereshs (seems random), the image is only displayed partially (1/2 to 1/3 in lower part is blank white) and takes a delay to finish loading.

How can I prevent this?

index.html

```
<html>
<body onload="update();">
    <script src="update.js"></script> 
    <div id="container">    
       <img id="img_display" src="my_image.png"/>
    </div>
</html>
```

update.js

```
function update() {
    update_image();
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
}

function update_image() {
    //timestamp as random identifier
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    //create image path, appending timestamp to force reload of image instead of using chached version
    var s_src = "my_image.png?random=" + timestamp;
    // preload image to prevent flashing
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = s_src;
    // get img container ID
    var s_id = "img_display";
    // refresh source parameter
    document.getElementById(s_id).src = s_src;
}
```

Comment: Your `<img` is missing its closing angle-bracket `>` and your `update_image` function has an extra closing `}` brace and you're inconsistently using semicolons. You also don't need to use a string in `setTimeout`, you can name the function directly: `setTimeout( update_image, 1000 );`.

Comment: True, sorry for the mess, copied out of a larger context too fast. All errors fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In update.js

/*Instead of */

`function update() {
    update_image();
    setTimeout("update();", 1000);
}`

/*Use */

**`function update() {
    setTimeout(function(){ update_image(); }, 1000);
}`**

Comment: Can you explain whats the major difference? How will this change my situation, since it doesn't address the preloading directly?

Comment: function update() {
    update_image();
    setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
This code will call the function recursively and trigger the setTimeout interval endlessly. It results in calling the update function power(n, n) times which leads to performance degradation.

function update() {
    setTimeout(function(){ update_image(); }, 1000);
}